# GDAX API ReferenceError: suite is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, referenceerror, coinbase-api

I am new to node.js and I am trying to use the GDAX API. I downloaded all of the programs and followed the [instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdax/tutorial). I have not edited any of the .js files and I am just trying to run one of the provided test files.

`npm outdated` has all dependencies with their Wanted version and `npm list` has all dependencies in the green as the tree structure.

I use `node public_client.js` to run the test file.

Note all of the code was cloned from a git repository.

Here is an image of the error:
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inmnX.png) (Not enough history to embed images)

Here is the error in terminal:

```
Alecs-MacBook-Pro:tests Alec$ node public_client.js
/Users/Alec/Documents/Trading/gdax-node/tests/public_client.js:9
suite('PublicClient');
^

ReferenceError: suite is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Alec/Documents/Trading/gdax-node/tests/public_client.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Here are the first nine lines of the file:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var nock = require('nock');

var Gdax = require('../index.js');
var publicClient = new Gdax.PublicClient();

var EXCHANGE_API_URL = 'https://api.gdax.com';

suite('PublicClient');
```

Here is the index file:

```
var PublicClient        = require('./lib/clients/public.js');
var WebsocketClient     = require('./lib/clients/websocket.js');
var AuthenticatedClient = require('./lib/clients/authenticated.js');
var Orderbook           = require('./lib/orderbook.js');
var OrderbookSync       = require('./lib/orderbook_sync.js');

module.exports = exports = {
  'PublicClient'       : PublicClient,
  'WebsocketClient'    : WebsocketClient,
  'AuthenticatedClient': AuthenticatedClient,
  'Orderbook'          : Orderbook,
  'OrderbookSync'      : OrderbookSync,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package is using `mocha` to run the tests. They have a `script` entry ready for that, so just run `npm test` and voila.

The command is using is in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --ui qunit --bail --reporter list tests/*.js"
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much.